# Cannot configure logging on SnappyData using conf/log4j.properties

Tags: snappydata

I am following this documentation to configure logging in snappydata:

http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/configuration/#logging

When I change conf/log4j.properties.template to "log4j.properties" and then stop/start all back up, I get ZERO logging in snappylead.log. When I start with no log4j.properties configured, I get 392KB in logging.

I also do not see my own classes logging either.

## log4j.properties

> log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
> log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=WARN
>
> log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
> log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
> log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
> log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
> log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
> log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
>
> log4j.logger.io.snappydata=DEBUG
>
> log4j.logger.com.pivotal.gemfirexd=INFO
>
> log4j.logger.my.own.classes=DEBUG

## snappyserver.log only has these lines

```
The netserver address, "dev-snappydata-1/10.0.18.66[1,527]", is already in use. 
The netserver address, "dev-snappydata-1/10.0.18.66[1,527]", is already in use. 

SnappyData Network Server - 10.4.2.0 beta - (1) started and ready to accept connections on port 1528 at 2016/08/12 17:39:58.841 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also added something like:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console
```

the behaviour is as expected. Since the intention here is to have the logging go to standard error, so the normal log files will have nothing.

For daemons like snappydata locators/leads/servers, the standard output/error has to be redirected somewhere else it gets lost. By default the console output/error of the lead/server/locator goes into `start_` prefixed log-files like `start_snappyserver.log` etc. You should find all the logging output in those files.

I will not recommend changing the logging target to be `console` instead of `file`. The default `log4j.properties` shipped with product is [this](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappy-store/blob/snappy/master/gemfire-shared/src/main/resources/store-log4j.properties) which is merged with user provided properties. Its best to avoid overwriting any of those properties and just add properties for your custom classes. Also its better to use command line options `-log-file` and `-log-level=fine/warning/...` for setting the global log-file and logging level (available levels are same as java.util.logging.Level like noted here: http://rowstore.docs.snappydata.io/docs/manage_guide/log-severity.html).